# Aptana javascript outline view

Tags: aptana

I have a problem with aptana and outline view.
I build my classes in this way :

```
(function(){
// My Class here
}());
```

Unfortunaly, outline view dont understant what's in this anonymous function.
Maybe aptana team can impr

Answer (score 0):

There is a ticket opened on it in Aptana Studio's bug tracking system: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-336.  You could watch the ticket for progress.